# MySQL many table join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**post_info** table contains many rows (many side) matching a single id.  I'm having trouble returning more than one row in my output.

[image]

```
SELECT user.*, post.*, post_info.*, board.* FROM user 
join post ON user.id = post.user_id
join post_info ON post.id = post_info.post_id 
WHERE user.id = 26;
```

I'm also not sure how to write my **board** table into the query either.

**user table:**

[image]

**post_info table:**

[image]

**post table:**

[image]

Comment: What's your exact problem?  Your query looks good to me and could easily return multiple results...

Comment: I'm only returning one row, even though post_info (many) contains many similar user ids (e.g. 26)

Comment: @user1040259 please provide example data.

Comment: @WorkSmarter I'm having trouble adding to sqlfiddle.  I'll keep trying thanks!

Comment: @WorkSmarter I added some screen shots. If I run the query for user.id = 26, I receive only one row from my post_info table.

Comment: @user1040259 It makes sense that you are getting the results you are. Post_id 26 corresponds to id 26 on the post table.  User ID 26 corresponds to id 23 on the post table.  This would be like comparing two different types of apples (Mackintosh vs Granny Smith). They might look the same, however they are entirely different ;)

Comment: @user1040259 What user_id is associated with Post.ID=26?  The current

Comment: @WorkSmarter Thank you!  seriously you are a master, it's my data and I can't believe I kept over looking that!  thank you, thank you!

Comment: @user1040259 Thank you for helping me make "Established User" status :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you write you board table into the query.  Additional join was added to represent the board to post relationship.

```
SELECT user.*, post.*, post_info.*, board.* FROM user 
join post ON user.id = post.user_id
join post_info ON post.id = post_info.post_id 
join board ON board.id = post.board_id
WHERE user.id = 26;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot board table in joins

```
SELECT 
    board.id     AS board_id,
    post_info.id AS info_id,
    user.id      AS user_id,
    post_id      AS post_id
FROM post
LEFT JOIN post_info ON 
    post_info.post_id=post.id
LEFT JOIN user ON 
    user.id=post.user_id
LEFT JOIN board ON 
    board.id=post.board_id
WHERE user.id = 26
```